# Как переменую string сделать в integer?

Tags: php, symfony3

Как перевести $string в integer используя filter_var?

```
$client = new Client();

    // Go to the booking.com website
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.booking.com/country.en-gb.html');

    $crawler = $crawler->filter('body#b2countryPage > div#bodyconstraint > div#bodyconstraint-inner > div.lp_flexible_layout_content_wrapper > div#countryTmpl > div.block_third > div.block_header');

    foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {

        //var_dump($domElement->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->textContent);

      //  var_dump($domElement->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->textContent);

        $string = $domElement->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->textContent

        var_dump(filter_var($string,   ));


        $countries = new Countries();


        $countries->setCountry($domElement->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->textContent);
        $countries->setHotels($domElement->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->textContent);

        $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');

        $em = $doctrine->getManager();

        $em->persist($countries);

        $em->flush();

      }
 }
```

}

Comment: `$integer = (int) $string;` и ни каких проблем.

Comment: Не не перевелось

Comment: А, все вышло спс большое